# Jquery ValidationEngine Swap Rule Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validation-engine

I have a dropdown box that contains contact "types" (Phone, Email, Postal Code, etc).

Depending on the selection, a second textbox needs to have different validation rules applied.

How can I dynamically add/remove `jquery.validationEngine` rules to/from the textbox? Here's the easy part.

```
$(function () {
    $("[id$=inputType]").change(function () {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "Phone":
            case "Mobile":
                break;
            case "Email":
                break;
            case "PostalCode":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use such logic here.
According [official documentation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/), you can use a function to validate your inputs using `funcCall[methodName]` directive.

So you can use code some thing like this:

```
<input value="" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]]" type="inputType" id="selectTypes" name="selectTypes" />

function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "Phone":
        case "Mobile":
            break;
        case "Email":
            break;
        case "PostalCode":
            break;
        default:
            return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
     }
  }
}
```